# Prime Number Finder has a mind of its own?

Tags: java, numbers

I am making a prime number finder, that would find the prime numbers for a given number that the user inputs.  What I have now seems to either miss primes, or add non-primes to the ArrayList.  My code seems logical to me, and I'm confused as to why this is happening.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or maybe a simpler way to do this (I feel like I am over-complicating)?  Some examples of errors would be: Enter 21, only 3 shows as a prime. Enter 11000, 25 and 55 show up (not prime obviously).  Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeFactors {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    long num;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\n\n\nThis program finds the prime factors of a given number.\n");
    System.out.print("Please enter the number: ");
    num = in.nextLong();
    System.out.println("\nThe prime factors are: " + primeFactor(num) + "\n");
}

public static ArrayList<Long> primeFactor(long n) {
    long output = 0;
    long guess = 2;
    ArrayList<Long> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Long>();

    while (guess <= n) {
        long primes = 0;
        long i = 2;
        long x = 0;
        long rt = 1;
        long duplicate = 0;

        output = n % guess;

        // Finds the sqrt.          
        while (x <= n) {
            x = rt * rt;
            rt++;
        }

        // Finds odd factors.    
        if ((output == 0) && (guess % 2 != 0)) {
            // This divides the odd factor by an incrementing number that is not 1 or the number itself.
            while (i < rt) {
                primes = primes + (guess % i);
                // If the sum of the remainders to the division is not 0, then the number is prime.
                // I used duplicate to make sure it didn't just go through once and count as prime.
                if (primes != 0){
                    // There were duplicates, so I added them for the division later.
                    duplicate = duplicate + guess;
                    // This was used to wait for the while loop to finish, then find if the amount of times the guess went through was equal to its value - 1 and another 1 for the final number (primes are only divisible by one and itself).
                    if (i == (factors - 1)) {
                        if ((duplicate / guess) == (guess- 2)) {
                            primeFactors.add(guess);
                        }
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        guess++;
    }
    return primeFactors;
}
}
```

Comment: Consider using either a debugger or a "poor man's debugger" (many calls to `System.out.println(stateOfSomeVariable)`) to monitor the state of your program's variables and thereby find out why your program is misbehaving. Edit: Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow, by the way!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that start by debugging your code. You can do this by either adding System.out.println() method calls throughout your code or by using a debugger. Use either of these methods to check that every single line of code behaves the way you expect. Most likely you will find one line that doesn't do what you want and if you don't immediately see how to fix it, you will have a much clearer idea of the problem and can ask another, more specific question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math and logic you're doing here is very strange and I don't quite follow what's happening.

To that end, I would vote +1 for making the code simpler.  This can be done with two simple methods.  The first method will find factors for a number and run them through a prime checker.  If they are a factor and pass the prime check, they get added to the array.

Bonus points: increase the speed of the algorithm by only searching through the bottom half of each of the factor checker and prime checker.  Logic being that any value beyond half a number cannot be a factor of that number.

More bonus points for speed, increment by 2 skipping all multiples of 2, since they are automatically not prime.  Good luck!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/***************************************************
 *
 * @file: PrimeFactors.java
 * @date: Mar 17, 2013
 * @author: AaronW
 */

/**
 *
 * @author AaronW
 */
public class PrimeFactors {

    public PrimeFactors() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long num;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\n\n\nThis program finds the prime factors of a given number.\n");
        System.out.print("Please enter the number: ");
        num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nThe factors are: " + findFactors((double)num) + "\n");
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> findFactors(Double num) {
        ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++) {
            System.out.println("Testing " + num + " % " + x + " = " + num % x);
            // First, let's see if a number is factor of your target number
            if (num % x == 0) {
                System.out.println(x + " is a factor");
                // Now that we know it's a factor, let's test to see if it's prime
                if (isPrime(x)) {
                    // If it's prime, add it to the ArrayList
                    System.out.println("And " + x + " is prime.");
                    factors.add(x);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("But " + x + " is not prime.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(x + " is not a factor");
            }
        }

        return factors;
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(double num) {
        // Let's start by assuming everything is prime and try to prove that false
        // If we fall through the loop without proving it false, we have a prime
        boolean prime = true;

        for (int x = 2; x < num; x++) {
            // if our target number can be divided by any number between 1 and itself, it is not prime
            if (num % x == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }

        return prime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Extremely helpful, thank you! I had it before so it would add a number if the remainder was 0 everytime, so without that being 1 or the number itself, I had (dup / factors) == (factors - 2) to kind of straighten that out. Using system printing was showing that it should work (for example, when entering 21, 7 would show up 5 times, so it should be prime - but never showed in the ArrayList), but simply wasn't.  Sorry for my awkward way of thinking lol!

Comment: It seemed like it was doing far more work than necessary.  Sometimes it's helpful to ask for a second opinion, get a new perspective on the problem, and start again.  Good luck!

Comment: Updated the post with comments to try to explain my crazy math (like I said I'm fairly new, so I don't know if there is an easier way to do things).  Edit: looks like I didn't find my error.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, instead of

```
    long x = 0;
    long z = 1;

    while (x <= n) {
        x = z * z;
        z++;
    }

    while (j < z) {
```

You can just do this

```
    z = (int) Math.Sqrt(n)
    while (j <= z) {
```

Then for each j I would check if it divides n with no remainder.

If it divides n with no remainder, divide n by j and add j to the prime factors. Then instead of incrementing j, try the same j again, for instance for 9 you do 3 twice for its factors.

Anything more complex than that is unnecessary - you will try each j until it can divide into n no more, and you will always try primes before composites formed of those primes, so you know off the bat you'll end up with only prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are a few problems with your code:

1. j, x, j & n, poorly named variables make for hard work debugging.
2. Where are your `System.out.println()` calls so you can see what is going on in your code?
3. The square root of n would be a more optimal point to stop looking for prime up to n.

Can I suggest you look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes for a rapid way of finding primes.

Comment: The variables where things I came up with on the spot (should have changed them before pasting it here - this is only my first post).  As for the println calls, I had tested them, but removed before pasting it here sorry if that would have helped.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion to make the code simpler. In you primeFactors method, first findout is it a factor, which I believe you are already doing, then call another method to determine if this is a prime. If that is prime add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some pseudo-code for a simple to implement (not efficient) algorithm:

```
the value to factorize is N
keep going until N is equal to one
  start at 2 and find lowest number X that divides N evenly
  X is one factor
  N/X is your new N to factor
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your variable names are inconsistent. `factors` is particularly bad, as it is only a guess of a single factor. Call it `guess` instead.
2. The arithmetic you do with `factors`, `primes`, and `dup` are also strange. Why are you adding to `dup` or `primes`? Try being your own computer, and executing your algorithm for the number 12; you'll see that you don't have a correct algorithm at all.
3. You've foreclosed the possibility of repeated factors by incrementing `factors` at the end.